# Cannot add "Wiz"(third-party) terraform provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am intergrating Wiz for AWS resources scanning, and following the doc : https://docs.wiz.io/wiz-docs/docs/auto-connect-clusters, wherein when I added wiz provider in terraform, it is giving following error,

In providers.tf, I added following code :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
  wiz = {
      version = " ~> 1.0"
      source = "tf.app.wiz.io/wizsec/wiz"
    }
  aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
```

Also, for Wiz integration, there is pre-requisite to have K8 provider and wiz client and secret added, for that I added :

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context   = //context
  config_path      = //path
}
provider "wiz" {
    client_id = //clientid
    secret = //secret.id
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There does not yet appear to be a wiz provider for Terraform, so that is why it cannot be found.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Yes, I checked on Terraform Registry, where it is not there for "wiz". Thanks for your input.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: Noted @ErmiyaEskandary ! I removed uploaded image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I could fetch `wiz` plugin from `tf.app.wiz.io` registry. The above `terraform init` should work.

The only case where I think it can fail is when you are using a module which expects `wiz` provider & you haven't defined the source `tf.app.wiz.io/wizsec/wiz` in all the modules you are sourcing. If you don't specify in each module, `terraform` assumes it needs to fetch from default registry `registry.terraform.io` & fails with above message.

You could specify the provider like below in each module & let the calling module specify the version you desire to have.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    wiz = {
      source  = "tf.app.wiz.io/wizsec/wiz"
    }    
  }
}
```

Are you calling a module which relies on `wiz` provider?

Comment: Thank you so much !! I added in all modules where needed and IT WORKED !! @harshavmb